# How can I sort files by their subject number (prefix of the filename) and create a new folder from it?

Tags: linux

The directory is called *Structural/* and here I have all T1 scans:

```
[1900140e@psych-sl04 Structural]$ ls

145951_DTI_T1.nii  
125645_DTI_T1.nii
164934_DTI_T1.nii ...
```

Now for this directory I need to create a new subdirectory for every subject like this:

```
Structural/145951/mri/orig/145951_DTI_T1.nii
Structural/125645/mri/orig/125645_DTI_T1.nii
```

So I need a new folder named after the subject ID, and within that directory two more new subdirectories where the (renamed) file is stored.

The directory where my files are stored now:

```
/home/1900140e/collab/3Sites_mat/Site1/Structural/
```

The directory as it is supposed to be:

```
/home/1900140e/collab/3Sites_mat/Site1/Structural/<subjID>/145951/mri/orig/
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I read about using the mv command and the rename command in combination with regular expressions but not sure how to use it when the date and subjectID are different for every file, because I don't know what to use as iterator to loop through the files (if that's even necessary)..

What I've tried so far included printing the filenames to a text file and trying to loop through all the lines to create the separate folders, but I feel like there should be a much more efficient way to do it.

Comment: First: `for i in *.mat;do mv -vf "$i" "${i#????????_}";done`. It is a trivial thing in Unix shellscripting.

Comment: For basic unix shellscripting, you can find https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Thanks for that! Does the # in this command delete every character specify after it? Trying to learn what it does so I can apply it to other things too!

Comment: No. `"${i#????????_}"` removes the first 8 character and a "`_`" from the beginning of the environment variable `i`, but only if its 9th character is a "`_`". The problem with your question is that it is not a question, it is a "write this script for me" request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following should work:

```sh
for i in *.nii; do
    dir="${i%%_*}/mri/orig"
    mkdir -p -- "$dir" && mv -- "$i" "$dir"
done
```

Here `${i%%_*}` [expands](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to the contents of `i` with any trailing substring matching `_*` cut off, i.e. it is the value of `$i` up to the first underscore.

Comment: Yes this does the trick! And thankyou for the explanation, sorry if it was a silly question, I'm very new to bash scripting :)

Comment: @MerelvanHoogdalem In the future, I'd recommend using the `bash` tag for questions about bash scripting, not `linux` or `mate`. :-)